# Azure AD Graph API ApproleAssignment does not allow zero GUID

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting an error when trying to add `AppRoleAssignment` for a user:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"One or more properties are invalid."},"date":"2017-10-21T14:49:42","requestId":"3aacf13e-5620-40da-8fd0-fb2d4130f171","values":null}}

When i use an actual `ApproleId`, everything works fine. However, when i set

`AppRoleAssignment.Id = new Guid();` i get the above error;

This does not make sense, because the documentation says that this is allowed
by setting zero GUID and the same has been stressed in other posts on SO.

What am i missing here?

Full code:

```
    AppRoleAssignment appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment()
    {

        Id = new Guid(),
        ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId),
        PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(user.ObjectId),
        PrincipalType = "User"
    };
    user.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);

    await user.UpdateAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, there are two scenarios we may get this issue.

First, if there is customize roles in the service principal you want to assign the default role.

Second, if we have already assigned the default role to that person before.

Please check whether you are in one of these two scenarios and let me know if you still have the problem about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with PowerShell:

`$EmptyGuid = [GUID]::Empty`

`New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $ManagedIdentityID -PrincipalId $ManagedIdentityID -AppRoleId $EmptyGuid -ResourceId $GraphResourceID.Id`

Error is: New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment : Cannot convert the literal '' to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'.

So it seems, that this is not working deep under the hood

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and I tried to use an empty GUID too for the **-AppRoleId** parameter as indicated by Microsoft to no avail.

What I found is that the **-AppRoleId** param does need to have a valid GUID, other than an empty one.

Initially, I was pulling my service principal using:

```
$app = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$targetapp'"
```

And then, I was trying to get the roles assigned to this app using:

```
$app.AppRoles
```

But $app.AppRoles would always return null.

Instead of using **Get-AzureADServicePrincipal**, which belongs to the AzureAD module, I replaced it with **Get-MgServicePrincipal**, which is part of MG-Graph, and by doing so, **$app.AppRoles** no longer returns a null value. Instead, it now returns the default role assigned to the application, and its GUID.

By using this GUID in the **"AppRoleId"** field, **New-MgGroupAppRoleAssignment** executed successfully.